# A simple crossword

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

**Right:**

**A2.** Moving through water
**M10.** Usually consists of sand and pebbles
**I8.** Yes
**H6.** Mythical sea monster
**L9.** A fish
**F14.** A praising poem
**H13.** The largest constellation
**A14.** A treasure hunter of the sea
**J13.** Therefore
**K8.** Seaweed
**E-F8.** Trust me, I am an …
**D7.** A high steep face of a rock
**G4.** A novel from Daniel Defoe
**H7.** Mollusk
**B6.** Used for rowing a boat
**H9.** H2O
**I2-J3.** A poem performed melodically
**F13.** A calming color
**{Blank}.** A sea voyage, mainly for pleasure.

**Down**

**C10.** Water moving in a circle
**E11.** A port
**M10.** Near or next to.
**D9.** Northern English form of oh.
**C13.** Conceal
**I8.** Keeps ships in one place
**L9.** An atoll
**J6.** A Japanese feudal clan from the Muromachi/Sengoku period
**N5.** A famous French science-fiction writer.
**A6.** A scary "triangle" in the sea
**J13.** A seaman
**E13.** A red fish is pulling your leg.
**N1.** Underwater vehicle
**B8-9.** A large crustacean
**H10.** A wooden disc with holes, used for tightening shrouds
**D12.** Riding ocean waves on a board
**H7.** Shore
**I5.** A musical note
**N12.** A type of gentle wind

[image: CROSSWORD]

Here  is a [google spreadsheet version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ykjzW6XyhiOVQVBH9HiOBumtJPtewX96LLwCHSycNcg/edit?usp=sharing) as well.

[image: A][image: B][image: C][image: D][image: E][image: F][image: G][image: H][image: I]
[image: J][image: K][image: L][image: M][image: N][image: O][image: P][image: Q][image: R]
[image: S][image: T][image: U][image: V][image: W][image: X][image: Y][image: Z][image]

Hint:

> I thought the solution would be pretty straightforward at this point, but maybe I am wrong and it is not so straightforward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this has been stale for a while, I think it might be relevant to post that I grow increasingly convinced of the fact that:

> the final grid should be read as a spiral.

Doing so gives me:

> ONCEWINEDARKFEAREDADOREDCANKILLORHEAL.AKEM..EACEFORGR.NT..ICA.BE.EA.LY.SLOWAS.HEGROUNDDISTURBE.ICANRAISEHIGHTHE.FALLHOMEORGRA.EUSE.AN.ABUSE.BRI.GING.OYOR.E.PAI.TREASURESI.ID.DANGEROUSY..VULNERABLE

With interpolations marked in lower case, some suggested by M Oehm and some of which OP helpfully completed in comments:

> ONCE WINE DARK
>  FEARED ADORED
>  CAN KILL OR HEAL
>  tAKE My pEACE FOR GRaNTed
>  I CAn BE dEAdLY
>  aS LOW AS tHE GROUND
>  DISTURBEd I CAN RAISE HIGH THEn FALL
>  HOME OR GRAvE
>  USEd ANd ABUSEd
>  BRInGING jOY OR dEsPAIr
>  TREASURES I hIDe
>  DANGEROUS Yet VULNERABLE

This looks a bit riddle-like to me, which is getting a bit out of my area :)

The next step should be identifying the answer:

> The answer of "ocean" after applying the letter mapping at the end of the puzzle would get us Cx49B, which actually happens to be the picture of a bay ([Navagio Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navagio), or Shipwreck Beach):
>
>  [image]
>
>  This answer also fits the overall theme of the crossword, whose answers are all related to the ocean.

Comment: Very good! I think ocean is a good answer; it goes with the theme of the crossword solutions. A stab at the incomplete line: tAKE My pEACE FOR GRaNTed / I CAn BE rEAlLY . SLOW / AS tHE GROUND DISTURBEd I CAN RAISE HIGH THEn FALL?

Comment: For what it's worth, Homer often used the phrase "wine-dark sea" in the Odyssey and the Illiad. The sea in question would be the Aegean.

Comment: Yes! That is correct. Can you identify the place also? :)

Answer (score 7):

Solved the crowssword:

> [image]

Gareth extracted the letters and put them in a table:

> `A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
>  
>   1   I . I D . d A N G E R O u S
>   2   S R G R A . E U S E . A N Y
>   3   E O R O U N D D I S T U . E
>   4   R E G O R G R . N T . R A .
>   5   u M E F A N K I L L . B B V
>   6   S O H E C A R K F O I E U U
>   7   a H . C D D N C E R C . S l
>   8   E L S A E E O E A H A I E N
>   9   R L A E R N I W R E . C . e
>  10   T A W . O D A D E A B A B R
>  11   . F O . M E K A . L E N R A
>  12   I . L S . Y L . A E . R I B
>  13   A E H T H G I H E S I A . L
>  14   P . E . R O Y O . G N I G E`

The following words can be found:

> DANGEROUS, VULNERABLE, KILL, FEAR, SIN (few others not along this theme)

Here are the individual answers:

Right:

> ```
> No.   Clue                                       Answer 
> ----------------------------------------------------------------
> A2    Moving through water                       SWIMMING
> M10   Usually consists of sand and pebbles       BEACH
> I8    Yes                                        AYE
> H6    Mythical sea monster                       KRAKEN
> L9    A fish                                     COD
> F14   A praising poem                            ODE
> H13   The largest constellation                  HYDRA
> A14   A treasure hunter of the sea               PIRATE
> J13   Therefore                                  SO
> K8    Seaweed                                    ALGAE
> E-F8  Trust me, I am an …                        ENGINEER
> D7    A high steep face of a rock                CLIFF
> G4    A novel from Daniel Defoe                  ROBINSON CRUSOE
> H7    Mollusk                                    CLAM
> B6    Used for rowing a boat                     OAR
> H9    H2O                                        WATER
> I2-J3 A poem performed melodically               SONG
> F13   A calming color                            GREEN
> BLANK A sea voyage, mainly for pleasure.         CRUISE
> ```

Down:

> ```
> No.   Clue                                                       Answer 
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> C10   Water moving in a circle                                   WHIRLPOOL
> E11   A port                                                     MARINA
> M10   Near or next to.                                           SO
> D9    Northern English form of oh.                               EE
> C13   Conceal                                                    HIDE
> I8    Keeps ships in one place                                   ANCHOR
> L9    An atoll                                                   CORAL REEF
> J6    A Japanese feudal clan from the Muromachi/Sengoku period   ODA
> N5    A famous French science-fiction writer.                    VERNE
> A6    A scary "triangle" in the sea                              SHARK
> J13   A seaman                                                   SAILOR
> E13   A red fish is pulling your leg.                            HERRING
> N1    Underwater vehicle                                         SUBMARINE
> B8-9  A large crustacean                                         LOBSTER
> H10   A wooden disc with holes, used for tightening shrouds      DEADEYE
> D12   Riding ocean waves on a board                              SURFING
> H7    Shore                                                      COAST
> I5    A musical note                                             LA
> N12   A type of gentle wind                                      BREEZE
> ```

Comment: I get the same answers as you and suggest SHARK for the one you don't have.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan that fits... thanks!

Comment: I spy DANGEROUS, VULNERABLE, ABUSE, KILL ... but it's not clear what to do with them.

Comment: There also seems to be a conflict on G4 but perhaps the fact that the "wrong" letter is from a RED HERRING is significant.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan maria deleva confirmed it was an error but said it doens't matter

Comment: Click the letters in the alphabet at the bottom of the question. Each letter is an individual image that links through to a DIFFERENT image. A=9, B=1, C=X etc

Comment: @Joe yeah we've already done that. See the second square in Gareth's answer

Answer (score 6):

I was a few minutes slower filling in the main grid than Beastly Gerbil, perhaps because I was also filling in this:

> `A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
>  
>   1   I . I D . d A N G E R O u S
>   2   S R G R A . E U S E . A N Y
>   3   E O R O U N D D I S T U . E
>   4   R E G O R G R . N T . R A .
>   5   u M E F A N K I L L . B B V
>   6   S O H E C A R K F O I E U U
>   7   a H . C D D N C E R C . S l
>   8   E L S A E E O E A H A I E N
>   9   R L A E R N I W R E . C . e
>  10   T A W . O D A D E A B A B R
>  11   . F O . M E K A . L E N R A
>  12   I . L S . Y L . A E . R I B
>  13   A E H T H G I H E S I A . L
>  14   P . E . R O Y O . G N I G E`

(lowercase letters are obviously-called-for interpolations) which, on translation via the key at the bottom (including the interpolations, which may or may not be a ludicrous mistake) yields

> `9 . 9 F . F 9 B R 4 0 C Z j
>  j 0 R 0 9 . 4 Z j 4 . 9 B G
>  4 C 0 C Z B F F 9 j S Z . 4
>  0 4 R C 0 R 0 . B S . 0 9 .
>  Z E 4 T 9 B V 9 d d . 1 1 a
>  j C A 4 x 9 0 V T C 9 4 Z Z
>  9 A . x F F B x 4 0 x . j d
>  4 d j 9 4 4 C 4 9 A 9 9 4 B
>  0 d 9 4 0 B 9 N 0 4 . x . 4
>  S 9 N . C F 9 F 4 9 1 9 1 0
>  . T C . E 4 V 9 . d 4 B 0 9
>  9 . d j . G d . 9 4 . 0 9 1
>  9 4 A S A R 9 A 4 j 9 9 . d
>  R . 4 . 0 C G C . R B 9 R 4`

The mix of uppercase, lowercase and digits suggests

> that we're meant to extract imgur images from this somehow

but whether or not that's right, it isn't clear to me how to proceed at this point. The grid (before translation)

> contains at least these words, including my interpolations: DANGEROUS, VULNERABLE, FEAR, KILL, SIN, FALL, ABUSE. But also these, which don't share their threatening feel: ROUND, USE, ANY, DUN, FAN, GIN, HOME, TREASURE. The last of those is (even though it uses two interpolations) probably deliberate. Dunno about the others.

Comment: The first grid looks good.

Comment: On the contrary, the first grid looks scary. DANGEROUS, VULNERABLE, KILL, SIN, FEAR, ...

Comment: Just wanted to note that the interpolations so far are correct. Also - you have some correct words, some incomplete ones and others (mostly the 3-letter ones) that are not correct.